# How to change the background color of the pickerInput() and also the options that are selected

Tags: r, shiny

I want to change the colour of the `pickerInput()` as well as change the background colour of the options of it is selected. Like for example if A and B are selected then they must have a different background colour say blue while the other options are still white. It will also be cool if the tickbox is moved towards the left of the options.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "my_select_input",label = "Select Letter", 
      choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),multiple = T
               )
                ),
  server = function(input,output,session) {
    observeEvent(input$my_select_input,{
      updatePickerInput(session,"my_select_input")
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: I don't know off-hand, but my guess is you'll have to change CSS manually. There are several good howtos/tutorials around the web about custom CSS in shiny apps, facilitated by the html-inspector of whichever browser you have handy.

Comment: I am actually trying to push that shiny app to a shiny server which does not support CSS. that's why needed some other way within the UI/server itself using HTML

Comment: Interesting problem, didn't know you could host a shiny server and completely disallow manual CSS. In that case, I think your only option would be to write custom functions with hard-coded or function-selectable colors.

Comment: I appreciate your comments

Comment: Hey @VedhaViyash, I' m facing similar issue now. just wondering have you figured out a way to do that or not?

Comment: Hi @Mr369, Still didn't figure it out. I just changed the page background to "#F5F5F5". But the answer will definitely be in changing some CSS arguments. Let me know if you find the solution. I'll update the answer if I find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to change the background color of the selected options in the `pickerInput()` input by manually adding the following CSS at the top of my UI. You need to isolate the "selected" class, which is automatically applied to the cells that are selected.

```
tags$style(HTML("

.selected {background-color:blue !important;}

"))
```

Comment: Thanks Dale, it worked like a charm. Do you know where I can find other keywords like these or are they all basic HTML/CSS tags that I already should be knowing?